# Multiple scheduling policies usage

Tags: linux-kernel, posix, scheduling

Can we use `SCHED_OTHER` and `SCHED_RR` for two threads, if so how will the CPU handle the threads with policy of Non-Realtime and Realtime.

Answer (score 1):

The realtime thread (with `SCHED_RR`, that is) will always preempt the non-realtime one (with `SCHED_OTHER`, that is).

In other words, the `SCHED_OTHER` thread will only get a chance to run when the SCHED_RR thread is blocked.

Comment: If suppose the threads with realtime policies continue for longer time, then what happen to the threads with SCHED_OTHER policies?

Comment: @Gughan: The SCHED_OTHER threads wait until the realtime threads give up the CPU. If the realtime thread never give up the CPU, the SCHED_OTHER threads never get a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

What @janneb said is true for the Linux implementation of POSIX. But since this question was also tagged `posix`, I shall quote what POSIX 7 [says about it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08_04_05):

> The effect of scheduling threads with the SCHED_OTHER policy in a system in which other threads are executing under SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR, or SCHED_SPORADIC is implementation-defined.

So what I can interpret from that is that POSIX does not specify what happens.